# How can I connect to my wifi connection if I am unable to find it in the network manager?

Tags: wireless, hp

I am a newbie and I just started using the latest Ubuntu. I have a Pavilion DM1 HP netbook and can't find my wifi connection in the network manager.

When i open the "network" thing, there's no "Auto Etho" no "Wireless networks" or "Enable Wireless" and when I go to edit connections then to "Wireless" I can't find my wifi connection, does this mean there's an issue with the wifi itself and how can I fix it?

Ethernet controller : Realtek .... . Network controller Ralink corp. Device 539f at the end, the others are practicly the same USB Controllers, PCI bridges, ISA brige, VGA and other stuff, but the more important are the two that I noted earlier since they're the network related ones.

Answer (score 4):

You should have listed wireless networks as you can see below

[image]

If you have a laptop be sure you have it enabled, some laptops have a hardware switch.

If yo still can't find it, try scanning for Additional drivers:

[image]

If you still can't find it, please open you're terminal and enter *lspci* and post the output here.

The ubuntu guide for this issue is posted on ubuntu [forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1776931) and you can see it [HERE](http://atinfinity.wordpress.com/2011/05/21/ralink-rt5390-wi-fi-driver-on-ubuntu-11-04/).

Oh and Tom below might be right, maybe the driver just doesn't load... open terminal and try:

> sudo modprobe rt3090sta

And if it works add this diver to your permanent driver list so it loads at start with:

> gksu gedit /etc/modules

and paste *rt3090sta* at the end of the file and save.
(or just do it with vi, whatever is easier for you)

good luck!

Comment: when I used the "additional drivers they said "no proprietary drivers are in use on this system" and before they showed some kind of warning saying I should check my network connection, I guess it's because I don't have any :(.
and here is the outpout for the lspci :

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1776880 I think that this is it, I'm going to do what they told me to, is it really it danizmax ? Because my netbook is also a Pavilion dm1 by HP !

Comment: Yes! looks like you did good job on finding guide with RPMs xD, but RPMs are for suse not ubuntu. Ubuntu uses deb packaged... I found a guide for ubuntu, I updated my post.

Answer (score 2):

*Before anything, make sure your hardware WiFi switch is on.  Then click the system tray `Network` icon and insure that both `Enable Networking` and `Enable Wireless` are on.*

**Method 1:**

If you know the SSID of your wireless network, click the WiFi icon in the tray, then click `Connect to Hidden Wireless Network` then type the SSID of your network in the `Network Name` box.

[image]

Next, select your network security type (if any) and enter your key.

[image]

When you are done with that, click `Connect`.  It should connect you to your wireless network.

If it doesn't work, make sure you entered your key correctly by clicking the `Show key` box.

**Method 2:**

Try accessing your wireless router (or access point) with another computer or OS.  Look for a `Broadcast SSID` option.  Turn this on if it is off, then save settings.  This will (hopefully) allow your computer to see the network.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. Unfortunately, I'm not at my home computer right now, and typing explanations on a smartphone is frustrating at best...

Open a terminal window and edit `/etc/modules` as 'root'. I'll use vi as an example:

`sudo vi /etc/modules`

Move your cursor to the end of the file, press `o`, then enter:

`rt3090sta`

Press ESC to exit edit mode.

Press `:wq` to exit the editor.

Reboot.

If this works, I'll explain why later; if it doesn't, I'm sure someone else will jump in and help.